# A string length is not printing out correctly with 0 in front

Tags: java

I'm working on a program that will ask for the first `9` digits of an ISBN number (`d1d2d3d4d5d6d7d8d9`) that the user inputs and then prints out the number with a `10`th digit based on an equation:

```
(d1 × 1 + d2 × 2 + d3 × 3 + d4 × 4 + d5 × 5 + d6 × 6 + d7 × 7 + d8 × 8 + d9 × 9)%11)
```

If the checksum is `10`, the last digit is denoted as `X` according to the problem. If not, the last number is added onto the ISBN. I have the program working other than when the integer begins with a 0 when entered by the user.

Ex

> Input: 113601267
>   Output: 113601267**6**

Ex.

> Input: 013032342
>   Output: "This is an invalid ISBN Entry!"

Here's my code:

```
int ISBN, r, i;
String st;

Scanner keyboard;
keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter the first 9 digits of your ISBN number:");
ISBN = keyboard.nextInt();

st = ("" + ISBN);

if (st.length() == 9){
    r = (st.charAt(0) * 1 + st.charAt(1) * 2 + st.charAt(2) * 3 + st.charAt(3) * 4 + st.charAt(4) * 5 + st.charAt(5) * 6 + st.charAt(6) * 7 + st.charAt(7) * 8 + st.charAt(8) * 9);

    if (r % 11 == 10){
        System.out.println("Your ISBN Number is: " + ISBN + "X");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(st);
        i = (ISBN * 10) + (r % 11);
        System.out.println("Your ISBN Number is: " + i);
    }   
}
else {
    System.out.println("This is an invalid ISBN entry!");
}
```

Where did I mess up, or what is going on?

Comment: you´re asking for an `int` so you are getting an `int`. A number doesn´t care for leading zeros and will stripe them. You could just use `keyboard.nextLine()` or `keyboard.next()` to begin with.

Comment: I could, but in the problem its stated: Write a program that prompts the user to enter the first 9 digits and displays the 10-digit ISBN,
including leading zeros. **Your program should read the input as an integer**

Comment: Your ISBN is a string not a number. The leading `0`s matter whereas a number will discard these.  You should just read it as  a String with `scanner.next()` instead of converting it to a number and then back into a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two bugs:

1. You should reformat your `String` to prepend 0 if needed.
2. You have `Strings`. A `String` is composed of `char`s. If your first ISBN digit is `1`, you'll actually do `'1'*1`. Since `'1'` is a char, you'll get the int value of the `char`, which is `49`. What you have to do is subtract '0' from each char to get the actual `int` value of each char:

   ```
   int ISBN, r, i;
   String st;

   Scanner keyboard;
   keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Please enter the first 9 digits of your ISBN number:");
   ISBN = keyboard.nextInt();

   st = String.format("%09d", ISBN); // fixes your 0-bug.

   if (st.length() == 9){
       r = ((st.charAt(0) - '0') * 1 // fixes your computation bug.
          + (st.charAt(1) - '0') * 2
          + (st.charAt(2) - '0') * 3
          + (st.charAt(3) - '0') * 4
          + (st.charAt(4) - '0') * 5
          + (st.charAt(5) - '0') * 6
          + (st.charAt(6) - '0') * 7
          + (st.charAt(7) - '0') * 8
          + (st.charAt(8) - '0') * 9);

       if (r % 11 == 10){
           System.out.println("Your ISBN Number is: " + ISBN + "X");
       }
       else {
           System.out.println(st);
           i = (ISBN * 10) + (r % 11);
           System.out.println("Your ISBN Number is: " + i);
       }

   }
   else {
       System.out.println("This is an invalid ISBN entry!");
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Its all running nice and fine, other than the st.length(). If the integer is leading with a 0, and I turn it into a string it's skipping to my else statement. Maybe its something with having an integer lead with a 0, but I'm told I need the input to be an integer.

Comment: An ISBN is not an `int` (or `long` or whatever number value). Tell that to your teacher. An ISBN is a numerical `String` value.

Comment: Thank you for your fix! I did what you said and I'm just having it print the String now instead of the ISBN integer. Problem seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

ISBN is more of a string than a number.

Have you tried this?

```
ISBN = keyboard.nextLine();
```

or

```
st = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()